# R: Prevent R from converting a column of "T" values into a boolean vector

Tags: r

Basically, I have 1.6GB file. One of the column contains all "T" values. When I read in the data, the values of that column become boolean values `TRUE`, which is not what I want. How can I make R ignore the column of 'T's as boolean values and read them as factors or characters such that it returns 'T' only ?

```
# READ DATA 
system.time(testing2 <- fread("testing.csv", header = T, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = T))

testing2$transtype49[1:10]
 [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

What I want is this (factors/characters not booleans):

```
testing2$transtype49[1:10]
 [1] T T T T T T T T T T
```

Comment: See the `colClasses` argument to `fread` for forcing a type of data.

Comment: Basically what @thelatmail said -- fread("testing.csv", header = T, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = T, colClasses=c(transtype49="character"))

Comment: By default T=TRUE. If you give command T = "T", your file may get read properly.

Comment: @rnso that's a really unnecessary hack.

Comment: @Kurtis why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @Kurtis, good answer but I would recommend spelling out `TRUE` as best practice.  Someday `T` will get redefined (also bad practice) and you'll spend several hours wondering what went wrong.

Comment: I found it highly ironic that you use an unquote `T` in arguments and then complained about the coercion.